# running c89 on visual studio 2013

Tags: c, gcc, c89, ansi-c

How can I force c89 standards in Visual Studio 2013?
I've switch "Disable Language Extensions" in to "Yes (/Za) and set warning to -Wall. The errors I want Visual studio to display is if I use // comments or also if I don't declare all variable at the top of a function.

Comment: MSVC does only support C90 (aka ISO-C90, aka ANSI-C89). It is not compliant to the C standard since ca. 17 years. Not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Curious: why do you want to use C89? If you need to support some very old platform, perhaps it's better to try and compile on that directly?

Comment: @Olaf: Apparently the problem is that it's not properly diagnosing code that is invalid in C89/C90, such as `//` comments and mixed declarations and statements.

Comment: @Olaf how can I force the compiler in MSVC 2013 to do what I said? (The // comments as well as declaring all variable at the top of a function)

Comment: @Olaf As in I want the errors to display stating these issues. It is not doing so

Comment: @YusufJama: Sorry, I don't use not standard compliant compilers and definitively not VS. And I don't use ancient C dialects either. There are good reasons to use modern C aside line-comments and mixing declarations and statements. Not sure why you don't want line-comments, they are very useful for commenting the code.

Comment: @Olaf When working in embedded systems modern C can not be used in a lot of cases (no modern compiler for the target platform / customers do not want to update to a new compiler / you build a multi-target engine and want to support old platforms / ... )

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorge: Do tell! That does not excuse using standard C on platforms you can get modern compilers which do support the standard. Re. embedded: Even MISRA moved on to C99 (though not standard C) and allows e.g. line-comments (which sane developer would not want those??). And with e.g. gcc there is a modern compiler at least for modern embedded CPUs (ARM, MSP430, many 8 bit MCUs, etc.). Support from modern compilers is one factor of design-decission. Sticking with outdated hardware and tools is often more expensive than moving on. ...

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorge: ... and is one task of good embedded consulting/system architecture. First rule: the customer does not know about current development. Without external help they'd stick with their 1980/90ies tools forever. (maintenance of legacies is a much more complicated subject)

Comment: @Olaf Of course no developer want to stick to these old standards, but if you are in a software company targeting embedded systems you only develop libraries for your customers and your customers choose the hard they want (I am currently working on a GUI library for embedded systems).
To come back to the subject, OP may not have the choice.

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorge: Well, I happen to have an embedded systems company and provide consulting from hardware to application-software. And I can assure you there is much less need to use those legacies than one might think after a first talk with a new customer. But it does require some efforts at convincing, good arguments and a good overal concept. From my experience, most developers just try to avoid these discussions. Until now my customers are very satisfied with my recommendations. YMMV, just don't claim your experiences are universally valid.

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorge: OP apparently uses MSVC. Do you know a platform it supports which is not also supported by at least gcc and clang? Re. "No developer wants ..." - There are way too many developers who stick with what they learned once and put a serious effort into **avoiding** to learn new tricks. Actually they are often the toughest problem when it comes to introducing new techiques in a company.